# Correct pixel dimensions regardless of screen size and resolution

Tags: java, android, canvas, matrix, bitmap

I draw a bitmap on a canvas like this:

```
float multiplier = (float) canvas.getWidth() / (float) background.getWidth();
Matrix bgMatrix = new Matrix();
bgMatrix.postScale(multiplier, multiplier);
canvas.drawBitmap(background, bgMatrix, paint);
```

`multiplier` is used to scale the image to fit the canvas.

Next I need to draw another bitmap on top of it, aligned to the center horizontally and a little bit above the center vertically. I calculate the center point of the second bitmap like this:

```
int centerX = (int) (canvas.getWidth() - overlay.getWidth() * multiplier) / 2;
int centerY = (int) (canvas.getHeight() - overlay.getHeight() * multiplier) / 2;
```

where `overlay` is the overlaying bitmap.

Everything so far is fine. Next part is where it gets tricky. I need to subtract 39 pixels (measured from the original image, "real pixels") from the vertical center point to get the right coordinates. However, as I scale the images and Android handles widths and heights relative to the screens resolution and the screen size, I don't know how I can make the 39 pixels look the same size on all devices.

Currently I draw the overlay image in this way

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(rotation, overlay.getWidth() / 2, overlay.getHeight() / 2);
matrix.postScale(multiplier, multiplier);
matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, matrix, paint);
```

How do I make the 39 pixel reduction look the same on all devices?

Comment: see `Matrix.map*` methods, in your case you have ta call: `bgMatrix.map*` and most likely you dont need the second Matrix at all, post an image of what you really want to achive

Comment: Where is the code applying your 39 pixels?

Comment: maybe this custom `View` will be helpful: http://codeshare.io/WCdf0, see how the second `Matrix` (`m1`) is made

Comment: @pskink Using `mapPoints` is equivalent to multiplying the coordinates with an multiplier as I'm already doing, that's not a problem. The original image is 567 pixels in width and 936 pixels in height. I need to scale the picture to fit the canvas (I used the `multiplier` variable), scale the other image with the same multiplier and center the second image to x = 282 and y = 429 which are dimensions in the original, unscaled image. How should I do this? @beworker Nowhere at the moment because I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: have you tried the link i already posted?

Comment: @pskink The page doesn't work. It says the page is offline.

Comment: yeah seems they have hard time now, try: http://pastebin.com/EJa5U4ME

Comment: do you know how it works, now ?